# Script browser behavior on the command line (linux)

Tags: shell, browser, scripting, command-line

I need to automate screenshots of a website. The screenshot needs to contain the browser window itself and the full web page (scrolled in multiple screenshots if necessary).

To do this I am opening a virtual display with vncserver, starting a browser in it, and taking screenshots with ImageMagicks "import".

Now I have a few problems:

- I don't know when the page has finished loading. Right now I'm just waiting a certain amount of time, which isn't a great solution.
- I can't open the next page in the same tab, so I have to restart the browser.
- I don't know how long the page really is and can't scroll the browser.

All this seems to be possible with iMacros, but it's not-quite-so-cheap payware and I can't find any other solution.

Does anyone know of a way to control any browser through command line options in Linux solving the above problems? Preferably a low-cost solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

[webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/) will render screenshots of any page, on OS X

Maybe [xvfb](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-gtk/2011-August/000629.html) would also work? (a webpage can be insanely long, I wouldn't jump head first for this solution)

Also [Chromeless](http://mozillalabs.com/chromeless) from Mozilla-Labs

Comment: The problem is that I need the browser in the screenshot, not just the webpage. xvfb would be what I am doing with vncserver now (albeit the better solution), but optimizing for the largest possible page would make the screenshots for the normal sized ones pointlessly large. :(

Comment: Can't you add a fake browser UI/chrome around your image?

Comment: Probably could, but these screenshots are for legal uses, and technically then they'd be forged. :P